# Store values into an array Android

Tags: android

In android development, is it possible to store values into an array. I want to store id's into an array. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Dou you have any problems running it or are you not familial with Java language?

Answer (score 1):

Your question does not make clear where you're having difficulties. If it's just the way on how to declare an array in Java, have a look at http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/arrays.doc.html